# Closing a durandal messageBox

Tags: durandal

The durandal messageBox is quite handy, however I don't see a way I can close it programatically (I may need to do this for example if the user hits the back button or any other scenario which fires `canDeactivate()`).

How can I programmatically close a messagebox?

As an alternative, an approach which would allow me to close all open dialogs (whether they were triggered via `show()` or `showMessage()`) would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, digging into the source code a bit made this pretty obvious.   `showMessage` just uses `show` under the covers, so we can just use the system MessageBox constructor to take advantage of the canned functionality while still having a handle to the VM in case we need to close it later.

```
var vm = new dialog.MessageBox('message', 'title', ['option1', 'option2']);
dialog.show(vm);

//somewhere else - forcibly close the dialog
dialog.close(vm);
```